# vue.js adding dynamic input fields based on menu selection

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue.js file set up, that is basically a repeater where I want it to leverage a switch case if a different option in the menu is selected. In this very case, I want if `MC` is selected for it to display the amount column(hidden initially) and display the selected amount of input boxes underneath by appending them to the DOM. I have been trying to get this to work in Vue.js but cannot get any further than where I am at.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: [4]
  },
  methods: {
    addRow: function() {
      var elem = document.createElement('tr');
      this.rows.push({
        title: ""
      });
    },
    removeElement: function(index) {
      this.rows.splice(index, 1);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Question</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Type</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Amount</strong></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
        <TD><input type="text"></TD>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>Single</option>
            <option>Mutlt</option>
            <option>MC</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
          <a v-on:click="removeElement(index);" style="cursor: pointer">Remove</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <button class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add row</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so basically just hide the "Amount"  select when you have selected `MC` for that row?

Comment: Amount column needs to be hidden when the page loads. When MC is selected- show the Amount column as well as that amount of input fields

Comment: what do you mean by "that amount of input fields"

Comment: if 2 is selected- dynamically add 2 input fields, if 4 is selected dynamically add 4 input fields

Comment: oh you're describing a situation where you would select "multiple choice" and have 4 answer options for instance. Why dont you put that in the question instead of a vague description of inputs

Answer (score 0):

Leverage [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html). Also define `type` and `amount` property for each row, and when the `type` is `mc`, then you display the amount select.

**Notice**: you don't have to manipulate the DOM directly when you are using Vue.js, manipulate only data properties.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: []
  },
  methods: {
    addRow: function() {
      this.rows.push({
        title: "",
        type: "",
        amount: ""
      });
    },
    removeElement: function(index) {
      this.rows.splice(index, 1);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Question</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Type</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Amount</strong></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
        <td><input type="text" v-model="row.title"></td>
        <td>
          <select v-model="row.type">
            <option value="single">Single</option>
            <option value="multi">Mutlt</option>
            <option value="mc">MC</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select v-show="row.type === 'mc'">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button @click="removeElement(index)">Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <button class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add row</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is part of it-trying to add dynamic input boxes that show amount--it can be as basic as an add button that allow multiple inputs under the question